# how can I extract specific string from text

Tags: bash, macos

I have a .txt file like this,

```
26S proteasome non-ATPase regulatory subunit 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PSMD1 PE=1 SV=1
Tensin-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TNS1 PE=1 SV=1
Integrin-linked protein kinase OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=ILK PE=1 SV=1
Glucose-6-phosphate isomerase (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GPI PE=1 SV=1
Fibulin-5 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=FBLN5 PE=1 SV=1
Tropomyosin alpha-1 chain (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TPM1 PE=1 SV=1
Cadherin-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=CDH1 PE=1 SV=1
```

I only want to extract the strings after `GN=`

I want to have an output like this

```
PSMD1
TNS1
ILK
GPI
FBLN5
TPM1
CDH1
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @ anubhava I don't know how to select the regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` on OSX:

```
awk -F ' GN=' '{sub(/[[:blank:]].*$/, "", $2); print $2}' file
```

```
PSMD1
TNS1
ILK
GPI
FBLN5
TPM1
CDH1
```

This `awk` command uses `GN=` as field separator. `$2` gives use as value after this token and `sub` function removes text starting with a whitespace in `$2`.

This `sed` should also work:

```
sed -E 's/.* GN=([^[:blank:]]+).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: can you explain how you came with the regular expression? I want to learn that

Comment: I have added in asnwer

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
$ grep -Po 'GN=\K[^[:space:]]+' file
PSMD1
TNS1
ILK
GPI
FBLN5
TPM1
CDH1
```

Comment: I did this but does not work `grep -Po 'GN=\K[^[:space:]]+' mydf.txt > out.txt
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: @Learner Are you maybe on macOS?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Yes I am

Comment: It's probably advisable to add `macOS` as a tag to any such questions because Apple ships somewhat outdated, or BSD-style, utilities rather than the leading-edge stuff Linux users enjoy.

Comment: Added the tag to avoid confusion